# Which Sport? A non math question

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, language

This relates to a sport, a great accomplishment.

[image]

It is a word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another long shot:

> **sixer** =  sì (4 in Chinese) + x + èr (2 in Chinese)
>
>  The sport is cricket (hope fair play here as this was supplied by OP). A sixer may be informal, as just 'six' is the common term for hitting the ball over the boundary, scoring 6 runs.

This answer was greatly assisted by hints and recent knowledge of Grandpa's languages.

---

First try: 
A shot at this. Is it a

> **Quadruple-double** as, quadruple is 4 times, and (using x again if needed) times 2 is double.
>
>  In basketball this is a double-digit number total in four of five - points, rebounds, assists, steals, blocked shots - in a game. In the NBA there have been four quadruple-doubles.

Comment: So I will give you a hint @Tom. My answer is Cricket as the sport and 4X2 is a single word used in it. With that and the Tag info you can get to it.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Swimming

Because

> The women's world record **4x2**00m freestyle swimming relay is 7:42.08
>  which, to the nearest second, is **462** seconds, i.e **4x2**s.
>
>  (This was set by Pang Jiaying, Yang Yu, Zhu Qianwei, and Liu Jing of The People's Republic Of China in Rome, 2009-07-30)

Comment: Then I would have said 4X200 not 2. But good guess.